# How to compare if a certain value all ready exist on my.settings vb.net

Tags: vb.net, hash

How to compare if a certain value all ready exist on my.settings vb.net
Hi i have start a new application and i have the application all much finish but i can not find the way to verify if a certain value its present on my.settings.md5_hashes .
So my application on the first form you can hash a string of each line on my text file and the insert is name and after the name its value.
My question is well i know how to retrieved the values and list the again on a listbox but how can i look if a certain string its exists?
this is my code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If My.Settings.md5_hashes Is Nothing Then My.Settings.md5_hashes = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection()

    Dim openfile = New OpenFileDialog()
    openfile.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt"
    If (openfile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim myfile As String = openfile.FileName
        Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(myfile)
        For Each line As String In allLines

            'ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
            Using hasher As MD5 = MD5.Create()    ' create hash object

                ' Convert to byte array and get hash
                Dim dbytes As Byte() =
                     hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line))

                ' sb to create string from bytes
                Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()

                ' convert byte data to hex string
                For n As Integer = 0 To dbytes.Length - 1
                    sBuilder.Append(dbytes(n).ToString("X2"))
                Next n

                ListBox1.Items.Add(line + "<--->" + sBuilder.ToString)
                My.Settings.md5_hashes.Add(line)
                My.Settings.md5_hashes.Add(sBuilder.ToString)

                My.Settings.Save()
            End Using
        Next


    End If

    For Each item In My.Settings.md5_hashes
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next



    If My.Settings.md5_hashes Is Nothing Then
        Return

    End If
    MsgBox("All Imported Hashed And saved!")
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()



End Sub
Shared Function GetHash(theInput As String) As String

    Using hasher As MD5 = MD5.Create()    ' create hash object

        ' Convert to byte array and get hash
        Dim dbytes As Byte() =
             hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theInput))

        ' sb to create string from bytes
        Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()

        ' convert byte data to hex string
        For n As Integer = 0 To dbytes.Length - 1
            sBuilder.Append(dbytes(n).ToString("X2"))
        Next n

        Return sBuilder.ToString()
    End Using

End Function

Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: i have find this example but its give me an error                                                                                                                If My.Settings.md5_hashes = (TextBox1.Text) Then

        End If
        
        If Not My.Settings.md5_hashes = (TextBox1.Text) Then
            Me.Show()
        End If

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.  I threw in a "GetStoredHash()" function, but it's not being used; thought you'll need one of those eventually, though:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If My.Settings.md5_hashes Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.md5_hashes = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection()
    End If

    Dim openfile As New OpenFileDialog()
    openfile.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt"
    If (openfile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim strHash As String
        For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(openfile.FileName)
            If Not IsValuePresent(line) Then ' prevent duplicates from being added to you collection
                strHash = GetHash(line)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(line + "<--->" + strHash)
                My.Settings.md5_hashes.Add(line)
                My.Settings.md5_hashes.Add(strHash)
                My.Settings.Save()
            End If
        Next
    End If

    MessageBox.Show("All Imported Hashed And saved!")
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Public Function GetHash(ByVal theInput As String) As String
    Static hasher As MD5 = MD5.Create()    ' create and KEEP hash object so it can be re-used
    Static sBuilder As New StringBuilder() ' sb to create string from bytes

    ' convert byte data to hex string
    sBuilder.Clear()
    For Each dbyte As Byte In hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theInput))
        sBuilder.Append(dbyte.ToString("X2"))
    Next

    Return sBuilder.ToString()
End Function

Private Function IsValuePresent(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
    If My.Settings.md5_hashes Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.md5_hashes = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection()
    End If
    Return My.Settings.md5_hashes.Contains(value)
End Function

Private Function GetStoredHash(ByVal value As String) As String
    If My.Settings.md5_hashes Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.md5_hashes = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection()
    End If
    Dim index As Integer = My.Settings.md5_hashes.IndexOf(value)
    If index <> -1 AndAlso (index + 1) < My.Settings.md5_hashes.Count Then
        Return My.Settings.md5_hashes.Item(index + 1)
    End If
    Return ""
End Function
```

Comment: Hi tanks @ Idle_Mind for the replay wen i search on textbox1.text how do i call the GetStoredHash